# unbiased estimator of $\frac{1}{p}$ of $\text{Bin}(1,p)$

Tags: statistical-inference, parameter-estimation

> Let, $X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n$ are random sample from $\text{Bin}(1,p)$. Find an unbiased estimator of $\dfrac{1}{p}$.

If I start with $T$ be an estimator, then $$\sum_{k=0}^{n}T(k)\space \binom{n}{k}p^k(1-p)^{n-k}=\frac{1}{p}$$

Multiplying $p$ both side, and taking $t=\dfrac{p}{1-p}$, I found that coefficient of $t^0$ do not match in both side. Hence we can not find $T$ in this way.

My question is, is there any alternative way to find an unbiased estimator of $1/p$ ? Any help appreciated!

Comment: You implicitely assumed that the desired estimator depended only on $X_1+X_2+\cdots+X_n$, but the proof is basically the same with the correct hypothesis, that is, for estimators based on the full vector $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. To see why, note that an estimator is a function $T$ defined on $S=\{0,1\}^n$ and that $T(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ being an unbiased estimator of $1/p$ for some given value of $p$ in $(0,1)$ means that $$\sum_{s\in S}T(s)p^{|s|}(1-p)^{n-|s|}=\frac1p$$ But the LHS is a polynomial with respect to $p$ (with degree at most $n$), hence ...

Comment: ... it cannot coincide with $1/p$ on the whole interval $(0,1)$.

Comment: okk, thanks @Did . I did a very bad mistake. I will modify it in my notebook. But about my main question, does that mean we can not have any u.e. for $1/p$. I mean there might be a different type of estimator which I don't know.

Comment: My comment rules out the possibility of **any** estimator of $1/p$ which would be unbiased for every $p$ in $(0,1)$ (and even, which would be unbiased for every $p$ in some much smaller subsets of $(0,1)$...).